# Pip/PyPi: python-systemd vs systemd-python

Tags: python, pip, systemd, pypi

A couple of months ago, I wrote a small Python service using systemd.journal. Pip list shows that I have `python-systemd (231)` installed in the corresponding virtualenv.

When I just tried to install the python-systemd package, I got [python-systemd (0.0.9)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-systemd/0.0.9) instead, which does not have a .journal submodule. The [python-systemd documentation](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd) says the module is available from pypi as `python-systemd`, however it seems that it is instead available as [systemd-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/systemd-python/234) (now in version 234).

Does anybody know if the package name has been changed? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the name changed in [September 2016](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/commit/3758d884d4eb4cd425560b6cac451c61a3780b0c):

> setup.py: change name to systemd-python
>
> This name is unused on pypi. Let's grab it.

The first release under that name was version 232.

The [README does mention this now](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/blob/master/README.md#installation):

> The project is also available on pypi as `systemd-python`.